# Update a table with group by and count =1 in mysql

Tags: mysql, group-by, duplicates

I have this sql query:

```
 SELECT *
 FROM caduti
 GROUP BY foto
 HAVING count(foto) = 1
```

I have table `caduti` with duplicate value in column `foto` and need to update the column `foto_ok` with value from column `foto` only for those value that are unique in the column.

I have tried several UPDATE statement like this one

```
UPDATE caduti
SET foto_ok=foto
FROM (
 SELECT *
 FROM caduti
 GROUP BY foto
 HAVING count(foto) = 1
)
```

but I cannot figure out how to make it work. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get the unique `foto` from inner query and then apply self join and update all rows.

```
 UPDATE (SELECT foto
 FROM caduti
 GROUP BY foto
 HAVING count(foto) = 1) u
 INNER JOIN caduti AS c ON c.foto = u.foto set foto_ok=u.foto;
```

Comment: Don't understand u and c what stands for. I have tried the query as it is, but give me 6 static error and a sql error #1052 - Column: 'foto' from field list is` ambiguous

Comment: @Pier67 of course you get the error. Because foto column was ambiguous. I have updated the answer. Also, u and c are just alias. I don't know, how you are not aware of alias naming.

Comment: I know what are alias naming , but it takes me some time to understand how to use it because I'm a newbie. In the end I substitute caduti for c and leave u as it is and it work! So thank you a lot!